# Adding an attribute to a configurable product

Tags: magento2

When adding new configurable products, I want to enter two prices. The normal price, plus a cost price (the price the item cost me).

I've added a product attribute for costprice. When I create a new configurable product, I can enter the new cost price for the item. However I want to add the cost price for the configurable products as each configuration can have a different cost price.

For example, image creating a t-shirt as the product and having different colours as the configurable items. I can enter a cost price for the t-shirt, but not for each configurable item. When the configurable items are generated, I can edit each of these 'virtual items' and enter a cost price, but I would like to enter the cost price when I enter the configurable item price.

Answer (score 0):

The configurable product wont have a cost price as it isn't a physical product - this is only the 'container' for the actual products that vary in size or colour

Add the cost price to each simple product associated with the configurable. This was you vary the cost price for each of the sizes as required.

Either edit the simple directly:

CATALOG > MANAGE PRODUCTS > YOUR SIMPLE SKU > PRICES

or manage the product from the configurable:

CATALOG > MANAGE PRODUCTS > YOUR CONFIGURABLE SKU > ASSOCIATED PRODUCTS > EDIT (the simple sku) //do not click on the item line as this will update the checkbox - click on the edit link//